# Install numpy on python3.5 (Win7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am a absolute newbie for python. I am quite frustrated by install new packages.

My computer is win 7 x86. The newest python3.5 is installed (the [official one](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/)).

The `pip` and `ez_stall` functions well already. I tried to install numpy by `pip install numpy` or `ez_stall numpy`, but both failed. The first error msg says I need `Visual Studio` installed, the second tell me it cannot find `numpy`.

So I go to download .zip file from [SF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/). The newest support for python is 3.4 (I have 3.5); I downloaded `numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe` anyway. It is not surprising that when I try to run the exe file, it complains that "Python 3.4 is required, which was not found in the registry. " Is there any work around?

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676609/numpy-python-3-4-1-installation-python-3-4-not-found-in-registry?rq=1) asked, but the answers there did not answer my question.

Comment: If you would like to avoid the hassle of compiling extension modules yourself you can use a binary distribution like `anaconda`

Comment: Thanks to the Python Extension Packages for Windows - Christoph Gohlke, I have installed pandas.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this. If like you said you already have pip installed, then install scipy and you'll have numpy installed.

```
  #On unix like environments
  sudo pip install scipy

  #on windows like environments
  pip install scipy
```

Or you could just download from there [site](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html) and compile. All steps for building are on that site

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it my installing miniconda, and from that numpy.

http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html